# How do I get a debugging log in linphone android app?

Tags: linphone

When I press "Send Log" on the About screen after enabling Debugging, it does precisely nothing without any hint of what could be wrong.

Comment: Can you provide more details to identify the problem.

Comment: I thought I have given all possible details. Android App. Enable Debug. Press "Send Log" on About Screen. Nothing happens.

Comment: I used these steps from from https://wiki.linphone.org    Go to ''Settings -> Advanced''
    Enable ''Debug''
    Go to ''About'' and click ''Clear logs'' to remove older logs
    Reproduce your issue
    Use ''About -> Send logs'' to send it by email to yourself
    Now, you can go to next step.